# StorageException has occurred. Object does not exist at location. Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404 202

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload image to Firebase storage and expecting result back (url) of that image , its working file few days ago , but I don't know what happened now its now working as expected , The image is uploading but am not getting result back

```
private val firebaseStorage: FirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()

private val storageReference: StorageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference("Profile_Pic")
```

```
override suspend fun saveImageToFirebase(uri : Uri)  : String? {

        var imageUri : String? = null

        Log.d("debug", "uploadImage")

            storageReference.child("${calendar.timeInMillis}").putFile(uri)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                              storageReference.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid!!).downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                        imageUri = uri.toString()
                        Log.d("debug", "uploadImage:  ${uri}")
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener{
                    it.printStackTrace()
                    Log.d("debug", "uploadImage:  ${it.message}")
                }

        return imageUri

    }
```

this is my code image is uploading to firebase but not getting downloadurl back

> error
>
> ```
> StorageException has occurred.
>                                                                                                     Object does not exist at location.
>                                                                                                      Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
> 2024-02-20 23:06:44.363 15198-15324 StorageException        com.hxt5gh.frontend                  E  {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
>                                                                                                     java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get a download URL from a different location where you completed an upload.  This is where you uploaded the file:

```
storageReference.child("${calendar.timeInMillis}")
```

This is where you're looking for a download URL:

```
storageReference.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid!!)
```

They're obviously not pointing to the same location.  Perhaps you meant to use the same reference that you used for the upload and the download URL.